# Want to know the font and styles used in these notes

Tags: fonts, formatting

I really like the way these notes are typeset. I want to know which font is used here and are there any default styles that can be invoked to get such a format. A few things I'm interested in knowing the implementation of are :

1. the font
2. footnotes are displayed in the right margin
3. in the title "Probability Review" although all alphabets are in capital their sizes are different

I am only interested in the formatting since it looks really pleasing to the eye.

Link : https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/lecture1.pdf

Comment: The document seem to have been typeset with `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}`. The title is typeset with `\textsc{Probability Review}` (small caps).

Comment: What prevents you from just asking the author in an email?

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press `CTRL + D` in Adobe Reader and you can see the used fonts (there is an extra fonts tab).

[image]

[image]

I addition, I would assume that the document was created using [tufte-latex – Document classes inspired by the work of Edward Tufte](https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex):

[image]

Comment: +1. I also to find a font I use this method.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks :). I now see that there are tons of answers in the linked duplicate :).

Comment: You do not have to thank me at all. :-) I always positively vote all because we all dedicate our time to others. Rarely vote negatively, when the question is absolutely out of the scope of LaTeX. Most of the modern computer fonts are from the image you entered.